# My MS Access control displays no text for appended items following an append query

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, controls, combobox

### Relevant Tables

```
                                  #One#
+----------+         +--------------+
|Quotations|  --->   |PurchaseOrders|
+----------+    |    +--------------+
         <One>  |  <Many>           |
                |                   v  #Many#
                |    +-----------+        +------------+ 
                v    |QuotedItems|  --->  |OrderedItems|
                     +-----------+        +------------+
                   <Many>      {One}    {Many}
```

---

### Form/Subform

`PurchaseOrders` - Master Form, many-to-one with `OrderedItems`
`OrderedItems`   - Datasheet-style subform, many-to-one with `PurchaseOrders`

`Quotations`- A table that is one-to-many with `PurchaseOrders` and used for querying
`QuotedItems`    - A table that is one-to-many with `OrderedItems` and used for querying

---

### Combo Box

The `Item` control resides in the `OrderedItems` subform. It is a combo box that runs the following ad hoc query:

```
SELECT [ID], [Code]
FROM   [QuotedItems]
WHERE  [QuotedItems].[Quotation] = Forms.PurchaseOrders.Quotation;
```

The combo box query runs the way I expect it to; there are no problems here. The `[ID]` column is hidden from view (column-width is zero).

---

### Problem

The problem comes when I try to append values from the `QuotedItems` table (filtered on the current quotation ID selected in the form) at the click of a button.

I created an append query to achieve this called `CopyQuotedItems2OrderedItems`:

```
INSERT INTO OrderedItems ( PurchaseOrder, Item, Quantity )
SELECT PurchaseOrders.ID, QuotedItems.Item, QuotedItems.Quantity
FROM (    Quotations
          INNER JOIN
          PurchaseOrders
          ON Quotations.ID = PurchaseOrders.Quotation
     )

     INNER JOIN

     QuotedItems

     ON Quotations.ID = QuotedItems.Quotation  

WHERE (((Quotations.ID)=[Forms].[PurchaseOrders].[Quotation]));
```

The <kbd>Copy Quoted Items</kbd> button in the `PurchaseOrders` form then runs the following code:

```
Private Sub CopyQuotedItems_Click()
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "CopyQuotedItems2OrderedItems"
End Sub
```

The append works as it should. However, the second field of the `INSERT` statement - which ties in to the `Item` control does not display anything, even after refreshing. The only way to make the item's `Code` visible is to select the combo box and choose an item from it.

---

### 1000 words...

**Before clicking** <kbd>Copy Quoted Items</kbd> (note that combo box has two entries in this case):

[alt text http://img251.imageshack.us/img251/9529/beforeappendwithcombo.png](http://img251.imageshack.us/img251/9529/beforeappendwithcombo.png)

**After Clicking** <kbd>Copy Quoted Items</kbd>:

### [alt text http://img651.imageshack.us/img651/8175/afterappendclick.png](http://img651.imageshack.us/img651/8175/afterappendclick.png)

### Questions

- Firstly, why can't I see my `Code` by default after running the append query? Is it because the value inserted by the append query is not bound to the combo box in some way?
- Secondly, am I barking up the wrong tree? If so, how else can I get it to display
  the `Code` column automatically?

Comment: I'm not clear on the issue. It sort of sounds like you mean that you've got the first column set to 0 width, but now you want it to display. If so, just change the width for column 1. It won't change the value returned by the combo box, just what displays.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton: I've reworded the question, hope my need is clearer. Thanks.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but the code above is inserting into the OrderedItems table, whereas the control you are having problems with is only selecting from QuotedItems, is there a misprint?

Comment: I am quite tired, so bear with me. If the insert is working as it should, you are missing a requery at some point, because you must requery after an insert, and I am having difficulty seeing where. Where have you put the requery, because it is not shown above?

Comment: @Remou: I tried the requery on the control yesterday, and it didn't work. Am I supposed to requery the subform?

Comment: What exactly was the code you used and where did you put it, main form or subform? I can assure you that a requery is needed, and I am beginning to suspect that both the control and the the form or subform that holds OrderedItems needs to be requeried.

Comment: @Remou: First of all, thanks for bearing with me on this. I used `Me.OrderedItems.Form.QuotedItem.Requery` within the `CopyQuotedItems_Click()` sub, just after the `DoCmd.OpenQuery` line. I've also added to that `Me.Refresh`, and `Me.OrderedItems.Form.Requery` as well. The insert works fine, the appended records are visible, but the `Item` field refuses to display anything unless I manually go into the combo box and select what I want.

Comment: Okay, I give up :) Is there anywhere you can post the mdb?

Comment: @Remou: Check the screenshots out first, just to be extra sure that you're with me on this!

Comment: I think I am with you, but I now reckon you have more than one issue, and it is much easier at this stage to look at the mdb, it's up to you.

Comment: So you want the whole database? It's .accdb btw.

Comment: accdb is fine, and as little or much as you are comfortable with. Nice looking forms, btw.

Comment: @Remou (& others): The link follows. Bear in mind that this is a works-in-progress, and I am a beginner. Please feel free to critique. http://www.megaupload.com/?d=W3XRYW6B

Comment: The problem here is that you are using look-up fields in tables. This is an anti-feature and will, IMHO, continue to make your life difficult. Because of this, you are not updating the item field with an item code but an item id: 2 rather than 30105-250G. Furthermore, 30105-250G is a value made up of parts. There are several approaches to fixing this, the easiest is probably to match up the model id again and extract the code field. However, I strongly recommend that you get rid of all look-up fields and work with relational design ideas.

Comment: @Remou: Thanks for the input. I'd appreciate an example to demonstrate your approach as well. Oh, and don't you want rep? I'll gladly accept your comment as an answer for the help you've given.

Comment: I get back to you on this. Give me a few hours.

Comment: See "The Evils of Lookup Fields in Tables": http://mvps.org/access/lookupfields.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I get you, but have you tried a Requery rather than a refresh?

```
 <Me or form/subform name>.CodeCombo.Requery
```

It may be necessary to requery the form or subform, but I do not think so.

**EDIT re Further Information**

The problem here is that you are using look-up fields in tables. This is an anti-feature and will, IMHO, continue to make your life difficult. Because of this, you are not updating the item field with an item code but an item id: 2 rather than 30105-250G. Furthermore, 30105-250G is a value made up of parts. There are several approaches to fixing this, the easiest is probably to match up the model id again and extract the code field. However, I strongly recommend that you get rid of all look-up fields and work with relational design ideas.

Comment: @Remou: Nope. Tried `Requery`ing the control, `Repaint`ing and `Refresh`ing the subform. Nothing's worked so far.

Comment: To help me get a handle on this, can you post the SQL for the subform, the button code and the requery code, noting where the requery code is run, please?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Access has not changed much from wayyyyyyy back in the 90s.  ;}

<>

We used to write procs which "faked it out" to force the control to refresh.  I don't have the code any longer; we used the old sendkeys equivalent brute-force.

I'm willing to be wrong, but in your situation that's the only thing we had which reliably worked.